# Get minimum date value from comparison of current row colum vs next row column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

[image]

I have a pandas df with 3 columns: `col1`, `col2`, `col3`. Values in column 1 and 3 may be empty in some cases. Column `col2` starts empty. Goal is to populate `col2`. I would like to iterate each row to compare each `col3` value of the current row to `col1` in the next row. `col2` should become the smallest date value (as you can see in the image).

How can I do this in pandas?

Comment: Please do not post `DataFrames` as images, they are painful to re-created. You can use `df.head().to_dict()` to provide reproducible data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `np.min` with `shift`

#### Sample Data

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['2013-12-19', '2014-12-16', '2015-02-06', '2016-01-22', 
                            '2016-02-24', '2016-04-25', '2017-04-13'],
                   'col3': ['2014-06-28', '2015-10-07', '2015-07-19', '2016-02-11', 
                            '2016-04-28', '2017-02-28', '2018-02-15']})
df = df.apply(pd.to_datetime)
```

#### Code

```
df['col2'] = np.min([df.col1.shift(-1).values, df.col3.values], axis=0)
```

#### Output `df`:

```
        col1       col3       col2
0 2013-12-19 2014-06-28 2014-06-28
1 2014-12-16 2015-10-07 2015-02-06
2 2015-02-06 2015-07-19 2015-07-19
3 2016-01-22 2016-02-11 2016-02-11
4 2016-02-24 2016-04-28 2016-04-25
5 2016-04-25 2017-02-28 2017-02-28
6 2017-04-13 2018-02-15 2018-02-15
```

Answer (score 0):

My apologies...I misread your question. I admit I skimmed reading it - sorry!

This should work...

```
for idx in range(len(df)-1):
    df.loc[idx, 'col2'] = min(df.loc[idx, 'col3'], df.loc[idx+1, 'col1'])
```

This will leave the last value in `col2` as `nan` due to the offset iteration.

Let me know if that helps!

Comment: Does this compare the current row column value to the next row column value?